# Conflicting declaration in c++

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

I have a cpp file as follows:

```
#include <iostream> 

#include "i.h"

using namespace std; 

typedef struct abc{
int a1;
int b1;
} abc_t, *abc;

void fun(abc x){
cout<<x->a1;
}

int main(){
abc val;
fun(val);
return 0;
}
```

The i.h file :

```
struct abc;

void fff(struct abc);
```

When I am compiling the code following error occurs:

```
t.cpp:8: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct abc* abc’

t.cpp:5: error: ‘struct abc’ has a previous declaration as ‘struct abc’

t.cpp: In function ‘void fun(abc)’:

t.cpp:11: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘abc’
```

If I save the cpp file as c file and compile using c compiler then everything works fine.
What is the issue with c++ compiler?

Comment: @alk I have edited the question

Comment: Why are you declaring the `struct` in the cpp file and not the header file?

Comment: This is not C, it's C++. And in C++ you can't have `typedef struct abc {} *abc;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In C**, this:

```
struct abc
{
   int a1;
   int b1;
};
```

creates a type `struct abc` (roughly speaking), but not a type `abc`.

That's why you use the `typedef` trick to create a type we can use without having to write `struct` everywhere:

```
typedef struct abc{
   int a1;
   int b1;
} abc_t;
```

Now you have the type `abc_t`, too, which is the same as `struct abc`. There is still no type `abc`.

So when you add on the declaration of a pointer called `abc`, that's valid, as the name is not taken yet.

---

**In C++**, the original declaration creates a type named `abc`. There is no need for the `typedef` trick, and your declaration of a pointer called `abc` is invalid because the name `abc` is taken.

---

#### Solution

You can disambiguate your names (and de-obfuscate the code) like so:

```
struct abc
{
   int a1;
   int b1;
};
typedef struct abc abc_t;
abc_t* ptr_to_abc;
```

Or, if you are writing C++ and don't need C compat, just this:

```
struct abc
{
   int a1;
   int b1;
};

abc* ptr_to_abc;
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo Because the OP asked why it worked in C but not C++. You can't answer that without comparing the two.

Comment: Ahhh... I didn't notice until now. Just saw rhe C++ tag and probably filtered out the C part. Good  catch.

Comment: @Ted Can't blame you 

Answer (score 10):

You've declared `abc` as both a struct and a pointer to a struct by using `typedef`. It's the same as doing:

```
struct abc {...};
typedef abc abc_t; // ok, abc_t is now an alias for abc
typedef abc *abc;  // error
```

Skip the `typedef`, `abc_t` and `*abc` and use the class (with all members public per default) `abc` as-is.

**i.h**

```
struct abc {
    int a1 = 0;
    int b1 = 0;
};

void fun(const abc& x);
```

**i.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "i.h"

void fun(const abc& x) {
    std::cout << x.a1 << "\n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>    
#include "i.h"

int main(){
    abc val;
    fun(val);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
struct abc;
```

in C++ declares the type `struct abc` as well as the type  `abc`, which then clashes with `typedef`'ing `...*abc` again.

In C it just declares `struct abc`, so `typedef`'ing `...*abc` does not produce a duplicate declaration.

Comment: I didn't get it

Comment: `typedef struct StructNAME {...} typedefNAME, otherTypedefNAME;` you can't have the same name for the struct and the typedef at the same time.

Comment: @KarthikKM • You cannot have the same identifier mean two different things.