# conflicting declaration for typedef when using C header in C++ application

Tags: c, c++11, compiler-errors

There is a header file say header1.h from a C library.
In header1.h,

```
  31 enum ConnectionState {
  32     InProgress = 0,
  33     BannerWaitEol = 1,
  34     BannerDone = 2,
  35     Finished = 3,
  36 };
  37 typedef uint8_t ConnectionState;
```

I use it in my C++ code as

```
extern "C"
{
#include "header1.h"
}
```

But I got a compile error

```
header1.h:37:17: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef uint8_t ConnectionState'
 typedef uint8_t ConnectionState;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
header1.h:31:6: note: previous declaration as 'enum ConnectionState'
 enum ConnectionState {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I read the post: [Conflicting declaration in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364494/conflicting-declaration-in-c). And now I understand it is the typedef difference between C and C++.
But I can not change header1.h because it is from a third-party library.  How do I use this header1.h in my C++ application? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It may be tricky. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @Eng CA The best approach is not to use this bad library.:)

Comment: @tstanisl gcc6 is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `push_macro`/`pop_macro` pragmas to redefine ConnectionState to some other name and undefined the macro.

Try this:

```
// define ConnectionState as no-op
#define ConnectionState  ConnectionState
#pragma push_macro("ConnectionState")
#undef ConnectionState

// replace ConnectionState with ConnectionState_ and reset the macro to no-op
#define ConnectionState ConnectionState_ _Pragma("pop_macro(\"ConnectionState\")")

#include "header1.h"
```

It will transform:

```
enum ConnectionState {
    InProgress = 0,
    BannerWaitEol = 1,
    BannerDone = 2,
    Finished = 3,
};
typedef uint8_t ConnectionState;
```

into this:

```
enum ConnectionState_ {
    InProgress = 0,
    BannerWaitEol = 1,
    BannerDone = 2,
    Finished = 3,
};
typedef uint8_t ConnectionState;
```

It should be enough to avoid redefinition errors as long as no-one uses `enum ConnectionState`.